# Can I use mysql queries to replace query_posts()?

Tags: mysql

I have a template that seems to only accept variables given though `query_posts()`, which appears to work like `get_posts()`, but it's too restricting. So I need to either do it somehow without `query_posts()` or find a way to include filters like

> posts that have one or more of several values in this meta value of this meta key with authors who have this value in their meta key

inside of it. So far I've been unsuccessfull with both.

Is there anything that would help me?

Comment: You say that the template does not accept anything but query_posts, which seems like a major bug to me. Can you elaborate a little more on this? I mean, what other than query_posts have you tried, and why did it not work?

Comment: You can modify the result of `query_posts()` using filters provided by WordPress. take a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what do you mean by template "accepting" variables.

`WP_Query` (which `query_posts()`/`get_posts()` are build on top of) is *very* flexible. In many cases it's not as much being *able* to do something with it, as having *experience* using it to achieve results.

Typically even when queries cannot be expressed in single set of arguments, it is still very possible to make "compound" queries, by querying partial post sets and further using them in additional queries.

That said it *is* quite possible to use raw SQL. As long as you retrieve records from posts table accurately, you can instance `WP_Post` objects from them. Note that this will skip much of related WP functionality, such as caching, etc.